# How do I take elements from diffrent XML files to create a new one through python?

Tags: python, xml

I have two xml files:

1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
```

I need to create a new xml file 3.xml which will have content from 1.xml and 2.xml like this:
3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <root>        
      <bookstore>
      <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
      </book>
      <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
      </book>
      <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
     </bookstore>
     <book category="WEB">
       <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
       <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
       <year>2003</year>
       <price>39.95</price>
     </book>
    </root>
```

I am using Python ElementTree Module to parse 1.xml and 2.xml and then create  a new file .but its giving me error: **TypeError: cannot serialize  (type Element)**
Code I am using is:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
#Tree for 1.xml
tree = ET.parse('1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
Bookstore = root.find('bookstore')
#Tree for 2.xml
tree2 = ET.parse('2.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()
#3.xml
root_element = ET.Element("root")
child = ET.SubElement(root_element,Bookstore)
child = ET.SubElement(root_element,root2)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_element)
tree.write("3.xml")
```

When I run this program it gives me "cannot serialize" error at end while writing to 3.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SubElement` function expects a tag name (text string) as the second argument, not an element . Instead of calling `SubElement` try `append`. The last part of your script should be:

```
#3.xml
root_element = ET.Element("root")
root_element.append(Bookstore)
root_element.append(root2)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_element)
tree.write("3.xml")
```